# nyAsa on murti during prANa pratishthA

Tags: worship, vedic-gods, pranapratishtha

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prana_Pratishtha) wikipedia article says that during prANa pratishthA, nyAsa is done ON THE MURTI where various deities are installed in various parts of murti.

> The ritual typically involves a Puja, chanting of Sanskrit mantras as the deity is moved from outside into the center place, inviting the deity as resident guest of the temple, bathing and cleansing the deity whose feet may be washed just like a revered guest arriving after a long journey, dressing and seating in a place of comfort, placing the image's face towards east (marking sunrise), **followed by Nyasa with hymns (act of touching different parts of the deity murti signifying the presence of various gods as sensory organs – Indra as hand, Brahma as heart, Surya as eyes, and so on),** spraying of scented water and flowers, with the Chaksunmilan (Sanskrit: चक्षन् मिलन, meeting the eye opening) ceremony marking the high point of the ritual.[6] The image is then considered as consecrated.

My questions are

1. Is this wikipedia claim true?

Edit: [This](http://kids.baps.org/thingstoknow/satsang/47.htm) site also mentions similar procedure of nyAsa on murti.

2. If true, what is full list of deities installed in various body parts of murti? If this differs from tradition to tradition then give any list you are aware of. I am not asking for nyAsa mantras or prANa pratishthA mantras or procedure or anything of that sort. Just list of deities and corresponding body parts of murti. Thank you.